# Programmatically enable sharding + choosing shard key on a collection using mongodb with Node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sharding

I am using Mongodb 3.2.1 and node js driver 2.2.4 in Ubuntu 14.04.How can I programmatically enable sharding for both db and also collection with hashed index.

Is this the correct way to excute in node js like below

```
db.runCommand({"enablesharding" : "ABC"})
```

If it so, how can execute for sharding collection with the key?.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, you could try to write your `.bat` file to enable sharding. The you can access this file using `fs` module of NodeJS. You can do similar things with other O.S.